# Grouped Table view in Iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I m using grouped table view in my app. I have 2 sections in table. first  section has 3 rows and second section has more than 10 rows .when I scrolled  sections it displays rows from section 1 after 5 th row of section second. what should I do.

Here is my code...

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 2;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            return 3;
            break;
            case 1:
            return 8;
                break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    return 5;
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    if (indexPath.section==0)
    {

        if (indexPath.row==0)
        {
            UILabel *Name=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 20)];
            [Name setText:@"First Name "];
            [cell.contentView  addSubview:Name];

            UITextField *textName=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140, 10, 150, 20)];
            textName.placeholder=@"Enter First Name";
            [textName setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
            textName.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
            textName.keyboardType=UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
            textName.returnKeyType=UIReturnKeyDone;
            textName.delegate=self;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:textName];


        }

    if (indexPath.row==1)
    {
        UILabel *Name=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 110, 20)];
        [Name setText:@"Middle Name"];
        [cell.contentView  addSubview:Name];

        UITextField *textName=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140, 10, 150, 20)];
        textName.placeholder=@"Enter Middle Name";
        [textName setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
        textName.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
        textName.keyboardType=UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
        textName.returnKeyType=UIReturnKeyDone;
        textName.delegate=self;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:textName];


    }

    if (indexPath.row==2)
    {
        UILabel *Name=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 20)];
        [Name setText:@"Last Name "];
        [cell.contentView  addSubview:Name];

        UITextField *textName=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140, 10, 150, 20)];
        textName.placeholder=@"Enter Last Name";
        [textName setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
        textName.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
        textName.keyboardType=UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
        textName.returnKeyType=UIReturnKeyDone;
        textName.delegate=self;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:textName];


    }
    }


    if (indexPath.section==1) {

        if (indexPath.row==0) {
            cell.textLabel.text=@"1";
        }
        if (indexPath.row==1) {
            cell.textLabel.text=@"2";
        }
        if (indexPath.row==2) {
            cell.textLabel.text=@"3";
        }
        if (indexPath.row==3) {
            cell.textLabel.text=@"4";
        }
        if (indexPath.row==4) {
            cell.textLabel.text=@"5";
        }
        if (indexPath.row==5) {
            cell.textLabel.text=@"6";
        }
        if (indexPath.row==6) {
            cell.textLabel.text=@"7";
        }
        if (indexPath.row==7) {
            cell.textLabel.text=@"8";
        }


    }


    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need 2 Cell identifiers. The problem is that you dequeue cells with the same identifier.
Paste the code and should work fine:D

P.S: I did not resolve your problems with your labels. You alloc them each time you display an cell. That is wrong.

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 2;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    NSInteger returnValue = 5;
    switch (section) {
        case 0:
        {
            returnValue = 3;
            break;
        }
        case 1:
        {
            returnValue = 8;
            break;
        }   
        default:
            break;
    }

    return returnValue;
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifierSection1 = @"Cell1";
    static NSString *CellIdentifierSection2 = @"Cell2";

    UITableViewCell *cell;      
    if (indexPath.section==0)
    {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifierSection1];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifierSection1] autorelease];
        }



        if (indexPath.row==0)
        {
            UILabel *Name=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 20)];
            [Name setText:@"First Name "];
            [cell.contentView  addSubview:Name];

            UITextField *textName=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140, 10, 150, 20)];
            textName.placeholder=@"Enter First Name";
            [textName setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
            textName.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
            textName.keyboardType=UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
            textName.returnKeyType=UIReturnKeyDone;
            textName.delegate=self;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:textName];


        }

        if (indexPath.row==1)
        {
            UILabel *Name=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 110, 20)];
            [Name setText:@"Middle Name"];
            [cell.contentView  addSubview:Name];

            UITextField *textName=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140, 10, 150, 20)];
            textName.placeholder=@"Enter Middle Name";
            [textName setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
            textName.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
            textName.keyboardType=UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
            textName.returnKeyType=UIReturnKeyDone;
            textName.delegate=self;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:textName];


        }

        if (indexPath.row==2)
        {
            UILabel *Name=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 20)];
            [Name setText:@"Last Name "];
            [cell.contentView  addSubview:Name];

            UITextField *textName=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140, 10, 150, 20)];
            textName.placeholder=@"Enter Last Name";
            [textName setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
            textName.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
            textName.keyboardType=UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
            textName.returnKeyType=UIReturnKeyDone;
            textName.delegate=self;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:textName];


        }
    }


    if (indexPath.section==1) {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifierSection2];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifierSection2] autorelease];
        }

        if (indexPath.row==0) {
            cell.textLabel.text=@"1";
        }
        if (indexPath.row==1) {
            cell.textLabel.text=@"2";
        }
        if (indexPath.row==2) {
            cell.textLabel.text=@"3";
        }
        if (indexPath.row==3) {
            cell.textLabel.text=@"4";
        }
        if (indexPath.row==4) {
            cell.textLabel.text=@"5";
        }
        if (indexPath.row==5) {
            cell.textLabel.text=@"6";
        }
        if (indexPath.row==6) {
            cell.textLabel.text=@"7";
        }
        if (indexPath.row==7) {
            cell.textLabel.text=@"8";
        }


    }


    return cell;
}
```

Edit:

You can use different identifier for each type of cell. So if you have  2 types of cell you use 2 identifiers if you have 1 type use one identifier and so on. The identifier is used to dequeue a specific type of cell, if no cell can be reused it will simply alloc a new one.

Comment: @Alex I'd really like to understand this better. Why does this situation call for two identifiers? Do you always need an identifier for each section? Thanks.